# Getting XML from two different files into a single SQL Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have the following query setup, that works with no problem:

```sql
WITH XmlFile (xmlData) AS
(
   SELECT CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\Timewise\results.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Timewise] ([Title], [IP])
SELECT c.value('(Title/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)') AS [NameSite]
       , 'video' as [JournalUserName]
       , '' as [JournalPassword]
       , c.value('(IP/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)') AS [IPAddress]
       , '4910' as [Port]
       , 'video' as [VideoUserName]
       , '' as [VideoPassword]
       , c.value('(IP/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(25)') AS [VideoIP]
       , '4910' as [VideoPort]
       , '1' as [TotalCams]
       , '1' as [TotalVideoWindows]
       , 'true' as [IsRemote]
       , 'false' as [IsDefaultSite]
       ,'' as [hasTwoDifferentUsers]
       , '' as [DVRType]
       , 'false' as [IsRemoteLiveDataRunning]
FROM XmlFile CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('DocumentElement/Server_x0020_List') AS t(c);
```

The next issue is that some of these nodes contain data from another xml file, located at D:\Timewise\JournalBrowserSiteSettings.xml

I tried to do some research on these, to get an example, and while I have the WITH statement covered:

```sql
WITH XmlFile (xmlData) AS
(
   SELECT CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\Timewise\results.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)
, 
 XmlFile2 (xmlData) AS
(
   SELECT CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
   FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\Timewise\JournalBrowserSiteSettings.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS y
)
```

I honestly have no idea how to pull this data (namely the TotalCams,TotalVideoWIndows,IsRemote, hasTwoDIfferentUsers, and DVRType) from the other file, and now almost 2 hours of searching has given me nothing to really go on.

Comment: Sadly your post has given us nothing to go on. We can't see your screen or the files and have no idea what you are trying to do. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for ideas on improving this question.

Comment: *next issue is that some of these nodes contain data from another xml file* ... how can first XML reference second XML for node data? Or are you making the connection between both files?

Comment: I am making the connection, as even the "title" and "NameSite" are the only two close connections, but they are listed separately.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you know how to get XML into SQL tables.

How about getting the XML files into two different tables and then joining the tables based on a common key, e.g. Title?

That will work. Won't it?

Comment: That would work, however there are no real connections in the XML files themselves.  In one, the Title is listed as like 111-01, and in the other, they are listed as "Store 111"